# Should we have have IF or ELSE type statements in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [this tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/31538/4), we have the following:

> Refers either to Microsoft's Windows operating system(s), **or** application windows.

*emphasis mine*

Is that kind of thing "allowed" or not? Or should we have a [ms-windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ms-windows) for Microsoft Windows, and a [windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows) for application windows?

> for the purposes of this meta post, please ignore the fact that we might not even *need* a application windows tag, because thats another discussion entirely.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please clarify? Oh, and note that 'or' in natural language can be ambiguous between logical OR and XOR.

Comment: @N.N. I understand that, however, I thought the purpose of a tag was that it was *just for that topic*, whereas this seems to have a dual purpose.

Comment: I do not think conjunctions or disjunctions are a problem is tags in general. They might simply connect expressions that are more or less synonymous. However cases where they clearly refer to separate topics seems undesirable, such as the case you refer to.

Comment: Personally, i think 'windows' is a tag which should be burned and split to 'ms-windows' and 'application-windows'.

Comment: It's not, strictly speaking, disallowed, but it's definitely (IMO) better to have specific, focused tags. If you were interested in questions about application windows and hate MS Windows with a fiery passion, you'd want to follow an [application-windows] tag and ignore a [ms-windows] tag, for example.